# Prevent an email address from going into Junkmail Domain Wide

Tags: exchange, outlook, group-policy, groups

The helpdesk has an email address and it all corespondense gets put into outlook junkmail.
Is there a way to flag this address as not junk in group policy or exchange server?
I know it can be done for a per user basis but that is a terrible way of doing it on a domain.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this, and it's quite easy. [This](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/45563/deploying-junk-mail-filter-lists-in-outlook-2003.html) article gives a brief explanation.

The real problem, though, is why are these emails getting flagged as spam in the first place. I'm not sure if this email address is used to send to email accounts outside of your domain; if it is, though, it's quite likely that it's ending up in other users' junk folders as well. Needless to say, you have no way to control or whitelist this address for them.

Comment: No it is only used internally so I will check out the article. Thanks for you answer.